# Fuse.js - search through nested values

Tags: javascript, fuse.js

I use `fuse.js` with `useExtendedSearch` enabled. I have an `array` of `objects`. Each of the `objects` has a key of type array that contains objects.

I want to search for values in both the outer **array** and the inner **array**. It works if the search keyword is in the outer **array**. But it does not work, if the inner **array** contains the search keyword.

In the code below, I want to filter the countries such that it contains only the object  whose `name` is exactly as the search keyword.

```js
const data = [{
    "continent": "Asia",
    countries: [{
        name: "Korea"
      },
      {
        name: "Japan"
      },
      {
        name: "China"
      },
      {
        name: "Pakistan"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "continent": "Europe",
    countries: [{
        name: "Albania"
      },
      {
        name: "France"
      },
      {
        name: "England"
      },
      {
        name: "Spain"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "continent": "Africa",
    countries: [{
        name: "Algeria"
      },
      {
        name: "Angola"
      },
      {
        name: "Benin"
      },
      {
        name: "South Africa"
      },
    ]
  }
]

const options = {
  useExtendedSearch: true,
  keys: [
    "continent",
    "countries.name"
  ]
};

const fuse = new Fuse(data, options);

// Change the pattern
const pattern = "=Pakistan"

console.log(fuse.search(pattern))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fuse.js@6.6.2"></script>
```

But it only filters the outer array.

```
[{
  "continent": "Asia",
  countries: [{
      name: "Korea"
    },
    {
      name: "Japan"
    },
    {
      name: "China"
    },
    {
      name: "Pakistan"
    },
  ]
}]
```

I expect it to retun:

```
 [{
  "continent": "Asia",
  countries: [{
    name: "Pakistan"
  }]
}]
```

Is  it possible to achive this in Fuse.js?